# AlertDialog's items not displayed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I create an `AlertDialog` with an `AlertDialog.Builder` and set some items with `setItems()`. The dialog is shown but I cannot see any of the items. All I see is the message.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
dialogBuilder.setMessage("Pick a color");
dialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {        
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do anything you want here
    }    
});

dialogBuilder.create().show();
```

If I set the `PositiveButton`, I can see that button just fine. I also tried setting `MultiChoiceItems` and `SingleChoiceItems` but neither of these work either.

Comment: Try to use `setTitle` instead `setMessage`. I assume that the builder is creating a usual message dialog because of that.

Comment: Oh yep, didn't notice that ..
It works, thanks !
How can I mark this post as "answered" ?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Use `setTitle` instead of `setMessage` which sets message body and overrides the items list.

Comment: quite difficult to spot this when using list items along with alert dialog.

Comment: How can one have both? Items and message?

Comment: @Armando, it's kind of hidden and may not have been there the whole time, but it's stated in the [Adding a List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) section of the dialog page: "Because the list appears in the dialog's content area, the dialog cannot show both a message and a list and you should set a title for the dialog with setTitle()."

Comment: @wow thanks. If the API has this limitation the linter should be able to warn you in the same way it is done with other Android specific features.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you go for `setTitle` instead of the `setMessage`? Try with `setTitle("Pick a color")`.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try `alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(view)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a message **AND** items, just use `setCustomTitle()` with a `TextView` like so:

```kotlin
dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(TextView(context).apply {
    setPadding(
       16.dpToPx().toInt(),
       16.dpToPx().toInt(),
       16.dpToPx().toInt(),
       0
    )
    setText(it.message)
    setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    textSize = 18f
})
dialogBuilder.setItems(...)
```

Note, that you cannot set a title this way, but of course you could create a custom title layout which support setting both the title **AND** the message.

`dpToPx()` is just a simple conversion extension function and not in the scope of your question, but here it is for completeness sake:

```kotlin
@JvmOverloads
@Dimension(unit = Dimension.PX)
fun Number.dpToPx(
    metrics: DisplayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
): Float {
    return toFloat() * metrics.density
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:-

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
dialogBuilder.setTitle("Pick a color");
dialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do anything you want here
    }

});
dialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
dialogBuilder.setTitle("Pick a color");
dialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{
}
});
dialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: `setSingleChoiceItems` is essentially the same as `setItems`: it's still exclusive with `setMessage`. The only difference is if you're implementing a persistent selection a radio button is shown for "single choice".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a resource string array you must include the resource packaging. 
context().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

My list was not showing by using the R.array.items until i gave the pointer the context and resource packaging.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setView(View)` with **ListView** if you want to achieve the effect of displaying a dialog with title, message and list of items at the same time.